# Undefined reference when passing an array from Fortran to C++

Tags: c++, fortran, intel-fortran

I am working on mixing Fortran code with C++. My main program is written in Fortran. Now I am passing array, e.g. dimension `x(0:100,1)` to my `C++` function. I need to change the value in the C++ function. Then return the array back. I have googled some solutions. But they don't work.

Fortran part:

```
integer m = 10
dimension x(0:100,1)
common /cart/ x
.... set the value for x
call cfun(m)
```

c++ part:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "defineMaxlen.h"

extern "C"{
   extern struct {
       double a[MAXINTERFACES][MAXLEN+1];  2 paras are defined in definemaxlen.h
   } cart_;
}

int cfun_(int m){
    printf("x value: %f2.6\n ", cart_.a[0][5]);
    printf("From doublecart: \n");
    for (int i=0;i<m+1;i++)
    {
        cart_.a[0][i] = cos(cart_.a[0][i]);
    }

    printf("x NEW value: %f2.6\n ", cart_.a[0][5]);

    return(1);
}
```

Comment: Your code, please. We can't help you without it.

Comment: The language is called Fortran, not ifortran. `ifort` is just the command dor the Intel Fortran Compiler.

Comment: You must make your C++ function `extern "C"`. I am sure there are several duplicates here already. See also [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding].

Comment: Please never say "they didn't work", say what really happened. Error messages? The same as before or different? Which ideas did you try?

Comment: I edited the post. I had a  new problem now.

Comment: Ask a new question then, the answer here must still make sense.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "defineMaxlen.h"

// because C is stupid.
typedef struct cart cart;

struct cart {
    double a[MAXINTERFACES][MAXLEN + 1]; // why do you need one more than you can use?
};

extern cart cart_;
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
int cfun_(int m)
{
    printf("x value: %f2.6\n ", cart_.a[0][5]);
    printf("From doublecart: \n");
    for (int i=0;i<m+1;i++)
    {
        cart_.a[0][i] = cos(cart_.a[0][i]);
    }

    printf("x NEW value: %f2.6\n ", cart_.a[0][5]);

    return 1;
}


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

## Explanation

The original code was written in C but, I assume compiled with a C++ compiler. This made the function, `cfun_` a C++ function, including name mangling. By wrapping the function in `extern "C"`, the function name is no longer mangled and is accessible as a regular C function.

The `struct` is no longer wrapped in `extern "C"`, since that doesn't do you any good. I declared, `typedef struct cart cart;` and defined, `struct cart {...};` separately -- I consider this to be best practice in C, because C is stupid when it comes to defining types.

The variable `cart_` is defined outside of the `struct cart`, to reduce confusion. Also, one of the things I consider best practice.

## Note:

I haven't compiled this and haven't tested it at all.

Comment: Why did you remove the underscore in `cfun_`?

Comment: @VladimirF Typo. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But now I'll ask, where's the array passing? That is, how does this function affect the array `x` is the Fortran program?  Or are you just addressing the "undefined reference" (based on name mangling) part?

Comment: @francescalus I'm just addressing the missing reference.

Comment: @Clearer, thanks for the reply. Sorry for the late response. I tried it. It works partially. I edited in the main post. Could you tell me how to solve it? or using binding C? Will it work for C++?

Comment: @Yue Please do not change your question so drastically. This answer was no longer making sense. You can ask a new question if the remaining problem is still large enough.